# Selenium Webdriver Download CSV

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am struggling using Selenium to download CSV file for couple of days. Please advise, much appreciated!!

I use Selenium Webdriver Language Bindings (Python) 2.4 + HTMLUnit browser.

Code:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("generate_csv").click()
csv_file = browser.page_source
```

In that webpage, if I use Firefox, after clicking "generate_csv" button, it will generate a CSV file, and usually download it. As I am using HTMLUnit, it is difficult to implement downloading files, so I use `page_source` attribute to get the CSV content.

Sometimes, it is successful!! But sometimes it will throw an error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not an HTML element
```

Could someone help me analyze why this happens? I am so confused that running the script is like throwing a dice.

Thank you.

Update: (Part of traceback)

```
14:29:15.913 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.selector: .controlbuttons > a > img[alt='CSV']])
14:29:16.404 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Returned node was not an HTML element
For documentation on this error, please visit: ...
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByCssSelector(HtmlUnitDriver.java:952)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:426)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1565)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1562)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.findElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
14:29:16.405 WARN - Exception: Returned node was not an HTML element
```

Comment: Could you show the full traceback? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using `explicit wait`

Comment: @alecxe Thanks! I just add part of traceback in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your html doesn't finish loading before you call the click on the generate csv button.  This happens a bunch with selenium when loading html from javascript - at least for me.

Not sure if this is the greatest way to handle it but I would use a recursive method to click until you get it...

```
import time
def generateCsv(browser):
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_id("generate_csv").click()
        csv_file = browser.page_source
    Except NoSuchElementException,e:
        time.sleep(3)
        generateCsv(browser)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: +1 for "HTML doesn't finish loading.. happens a bunch with Selenium"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since all the data is on the webpage, I end up with downloading the whole html file content, and parse it into CSV file.